# How to bring back the Undo button after it's hidden

Tags: google-drive

I moved a Google Drive folder and I want to undo that action. A popup came up briefly as shown, but then it hid itself before I realized that I needed to Undo it. How can I bring it back up again or otherwise Undo the action now?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the Google Drive Help page [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Drive on the web](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044?hl=en) gives the shortcut:

```
 Undo last action     Ctrl + z (Chrome OS, Windows)
                      ⌘ + z (Mac)
```

This will work after the *Undo* option has disappeared and even if you browse through folders in Google Drive. However, if you close or refresh (**F5**) the page, you will not be able to undo the last action.

Answer (score 1):

To 'undo' now find what it was you moved, where it is now, and move it back (*in*) to where it use to be, in much the same way as you moved it *out* in the first place.

Comment: @SimonWoodside Google Drive Help [Find or recover a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en) gives specific steps on how to do what pnuts said.